# android getSharedPreferences error: Map value without name attribute: boolean

Tags: android

I am trying to figure out the cause of this error it occurs on startup when i try to get the shared preferences for the app. the code is just:

settings = this.getSharedPreferences(Globals.PREFS_NAME, 0)

Seems like a corruption, but the bug is in the app as i have installed it on multiple devices and the same error occurs. I have uninstalled the app and re-installed it to no avail. also did a fully clean build. I googled the error and dont seem to be able to find anything on it.

I was previously working fine. so I am a rather stumped. Any leads would be *very* highly appreciated ...

regards,

### rob

```
W/ApplicationContext( 1541): getSharedPreferences
W/ApplicationContext( 1541): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Map value without name attribute: boolean
W/ApplicationContext( 1541):    at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.readThisMapXml(XmlUtils.java:521)
W/ApplicationContext( 1541):    at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.readThisValueXml(XmlUtils.java:733)
W/ApplicationContext( 1541):    at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.readValueXml(XmlUtils.java:667)
W/ApplicationContext( 1541):    at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.readMapXml(XmlUtils.java:470)
W/ApplicationContext( 1541):    at android.app.ContextImpl.getSharedPreferences(ContextImpl.java:376)
W/ApplicationContext( 1541):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:146)
W/ApplicationContext( 1541):    at net.robmunro.mypod.WelcomeActivity.onEWCreate(WelcomeActivity.java:160)
W/ApplicationContext( 1541):    at net.robmunro.mypod.AbstractEWActivity.onCreate(AbstractEWActivity.java:25)
W/ApplicationContext( 1541):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
W/ApplicationContext( 1541):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
W/ApplicationContext( 1541):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
W/ApplicationContext( 1541):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
W/ApplicationContext( 1541):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
W/ApplicationContext( 1541):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
W/ApplicationContext( 1541):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
W/ApplicationContext( 1541):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
W/ApplicationContext( 1541):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/ApplicationContext( 1541):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
W/ApplicationContext( 1541):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
W/ApplicationContext( 1541):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
W/ApplicationContext( 1541):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What's your `Globals.PREFS_NAME`?

Comment: public static final String PREFS_NAME = "com.mypod.intent.PREFERENCES";

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you able to reproduce this on emulator? If yes, then you could extract the prefs file using Eclipse DDMS tools to investigate the contents of the prefs file.

Comment: thanks for the tip. 
the prefs file was
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
<boolean value="false" />
<boolean name="initialised" value="true" />
<boolean name="upd.auto" value="true" />
<long name="backup.last" value="1300662039054" />
<string name="msg.read">0.995.18Beta</string>
</map>

turns out i was writing a null preference name to the prefs - so the error was correct - though I don't think the API should let you do that since the prefs cant be read after that.

anyways, a bit of a schoolboy error, but got there ... 


thanks for the quick reply,
rob

Answer (score 3):

thanks for the tip. 
the prefs file was

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
<boolean value="false" />
<boolean name="initialised" value="true" />
<boolean name="upd.auto" value="true" />
<long name="backup.last" value="1300662039054" />
<string name="msg.read">0.995.18Beta</string>
</map>
```

turns out i was writing a null preference name to the prefs - so the error was correct - though I don't think the API should let you do that since the prefs cant be read after that.

anyways, a bit of a schoolboy error, but got there ...

thanks for the quick reply,
rob

Comment: Managed to [reproduce](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19621603/281545) and asked at google [groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/JpDzZtbrjfA)

Comment: I tried it on emulator and it is working fine there. so what it means? problem in my phone or in code? my preference xml file do not have any missing key or value. everything is looking as expected and correct there.

Answer (score 1):

In my case

```
public static String docsDownloadStatus;

    SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(
            "Pref-Values", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
>>>>    editor.putString(docsDownloadStatus, value);
    editor.commit();
```

"docsDownloadStatus" is not initialized because of this whole shared pref file was corrupted.
After initializing docsDownloadStatus key everything worked fine.