# Why shared preferences has been reset up on app crash or force close Android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have taken CSIPSIMPLE code and repackaged to com.mycompany.appname

The problem is, whenever app is crashed, All values are deleted from Shared preferences.

Why?

My Application is

```
public class BeemApplication extends Application {

    static BeemApplication application = null;

    public static SharedPreferences mPref;
    public static Editor mEditor;

    public BeemApplication() {

    }

    public static BeemApplication getInstance() {
        if(application != null) {
            return application;
        } else {
            return new BeemApplication();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        application = this;
        mPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        mEditor = mPref.edit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTerminate() {
        super.onTerminate();
    }

}
```

In Activity I will get them like ,

```
BeemApplication.mEditor.putString(ctx.getString(R.string.pref_online_number), number).commit();

BeemApplication.mPref.getString(ctx.getString(R.string.pref_online_number), number).commit();
```

Comment: do post logcat incase of `crashes`

Comment: "All values are deleted from Shared preferences" -- what is your evidence of this?

Comment: Make sure that no one of your preferences items was getting saved with a **null key**, because after the crash when your app try to load the preferences.xml file, it can cause a preferences crash and preferences will be reseted.

Comment: remember to call .commit()

Comment: @CommonsWare, When ever i am trying to get stored values, it is giving default values

Comment: @Rami, How will be the null key, All keys are stored in string.xml file

Comment: @maveňツ, For every crash it is not resetting the values. It is some times like while receiving messages. If I crash it by myself with null value , Preferences are not being reset.

Comment: @GangadharNimbally in string.xml, something like that: <string name="youKeyName"></string> produce a null value.

Comment: @Rami, No there is no such value in string.xml

Answer (score 1):

This is common issue that many have faced including myself.
Have a look at this post [Android - Shared Preferences are lost sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943573/android-shared-preferences-are-lost-sometimes) which shares your findings.

I would recommend not storing persistent data across shared preferences and rather use something like a database table to store settings.