# android - Shared Preference not updating after closing app

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am using following code to add preference in `onStop()` and retrieving in `onActivityCreated()` .Everything works fine but after killing the app sharedpreference is not updating its value and a value inserted first time after installing app is remain all the time.

code:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    SharedPreferences appdata = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getActivity());

    etA.setText(appdata.getString("A", ""));
    etB.setText(appdata.getString("B", ""));
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    SharedPreferences appdata = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getActivity());
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = appdata.edit();
    editor.putString("A", etA.getText().toString());
    editor.putString("B", etB.getText().toString());
    editor.commit();
}
```

Comment: How you are killing your app. Please put a log message in stop and check in logcat if it is getting called when you are killing your app. Also put one log in onActivityCreated and check if it getting called when you restart your app.

Comment: are you un-installing the app?

Comment: instead of `onstop` write this code in `onpause()`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9837540/2826147

Comment: put log in both methods and both are accessed @ sagar trehan

Comment: @Madhur: If application is going in background then onStop() should get called for sure. Why you are suggesting to move code to onPause() from onStop(). Please reply

Comment: @SagarTrehan  as per the the life cycle onpause will be called first before onstop this is only the reason, nothing else

Comment: No change after putting in onPause() @Madhur

Comment: did you try to clear before putting in shared pref

Comment: `SharedPreferences.Editor editor = appdata.edit();
editor.clear();
    editor.putString("A", etA.getText().toString());
    editor.putString("B", etB.getText().toString());
    editor.commit();`

Comment: @Parsania: I posted my code, please check now.

Comment: It was missing editor.clear(); method @Mathur and Sagar Trehan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an Activity that which contains a fragment:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_layout, new ContentFragment())
                .commit();
    }

    public static class ContentFragment extends Fragment {

        EditText etA, etB;

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false);
            etA = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_a);
            etB = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_b);
            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            SharedPreferences appdata = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
            etA.setText(appdata.getString("A", ""));
            etB.setText(appdata.getString("B", ""));
        }

        @Override
        public void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            SharedPreferences appdata = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = appdata.edit();
            editor.putString("A", etA.getText().toString());
            editor.putString("B", etB.getText().toString());
            editor.commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Fragment layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_a"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_b"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I tested this code and its working perfectly for me. Please check and let us know what you are doing wrong?

Comment: Thats good it solved. But still not able to understand why you have to do editor.clear() for make it work. The code that I have posted is working properly for me without doing editor.clear()