# Map Value without name attribute : string

Tags: android, exception, sharedpreferences

I have used `sharedpreference` in my app and the problem is when I force close or remove app from recent application and open it again, It gives me exception saying `Map Value without name attribute` and preference value is reset.

I looked for this problem over `stackoverflow` and I found some of the similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368442/android-getsharedpreferences-error-map-value-without-name-attribute-boolean) and [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/i3XK_esyo3w).

after following these questions I tried to reproduce the problem in emulator but there it has not given me any exception or reset of preference xml. I pulled out xml file by DDMS from emulator data folder and everything there is looking fine. every value had a non empty key name.

Logcat exception while running on real device:

```
03-17 14:59:55.099: W/SharedPreferencesImpl(8636): getSharedPreferences
03-17 14:59:55.099: W/SharedPreferencesImpl(8636): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Map value without name attribute: string
03-17 14:59:55.099: W/SharedPreferencesImpl(8636):  at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.readThisMapXml(XmlUtils.java:568)
03-17 14:59:55.099: W/SharedPreferencesImpl(8636):  at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.readThisValueXml(XmlUtils.java:821)
03-17 14:59:55.099: W/SharedPreferencesImpl(8636):  at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.readValueXml(XmlUtils.java:755)
03-17 14:59:55.099: W/SharedPreferencesImpl(8636):  at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.readMapXml(XmlUtils.java:494)
03-17 14:59:55.099: W/SharedPreferencesImpl(8636):  at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.loadFromDiskLocked(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:113)
03-17 14:59:55.099: W/SharedPreferencesImpl(8636):  at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.access$000(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:48)
03-17 14:59:55.099: W/SharedPreferencesImpl(8636):  at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$1.run(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:87)
```

So here is what i want to ask :

1. Is there any problem in code or problem in mobile device?

   ```
   shared = getSharedPreferences(PreferenceHandler.PREFS,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   Log.i(TAG,"preference object created");
   last = shared.getInt(PreferenceHandler.LASTACTIVITY,PreferenceHandler.DEFAULTINT);
   ```
2. If problem is with my device what should I do to correct it?

Comment: Do you `commit()` the changes each time?  Or at least, in your `onPause()`.

Comment: yes. I commit it at the end of the method in which I am putting values to sharedPreference. same code is working in emulator also. Before force close I check preference xml file of emulator and it has stored the value. Also, is commit really lead to this problem? if key-value pair is not stored it will return default value, but in my case it is saying that name attribute is null which I checked in log and is not null.

Comment: You're right, I was just wondering if there might be some caching going on leading to a corrupt file but if you've examined the XML, that's not the case.  This is strange.  If you find an answer, please come back to post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am answering my own question for those who have similar pproblem.

I was removing items from list and maintaining state of list items in sharedpreference. I have switch case which  have default case where I was setting key value to null. and as because my for loop logic was wrong I found that it was sure to get into default case once if i remove any item.

```
    switch (i + 1) {

    case 0:
        pref_1 = PreferenceHandler.constantA1;
        pref_2 = PreferenceHandler.constantB1;
        pref_3 = PreferenceHandler.constantC1;
        break;

    case 1:
        pref_1 = PreferenceHandler.constantA2;
        pref_2 = PreferenceHandler.constantB2;
        pref_3 = PreferenceHandler.constantC2;
        break;


    case default:
        pref_1 =null;
        pref_2 = null;
        pref_3 = null;
        break;
```

Once I debug my for loop logic and removed default case to be sure no null key to be used in sharedpreference and to get exception if my for loop logic still wrong. and it is working fine now.

So if anyone getting similar type of exception and not able to find out where it is using null key, try to find out what is the step after which it is raising exception and then check it.
I HOPE IT WILL HELP SOMEONE!!! :)

Comment: I needed to read http://toastdroid.com/2014/07/04/null-shared-preference-key-bad-news-droids/ before understanding what was going on.